# Uikit3 has problem in microsoft edge browser

Tags: uikit, microsoft-edge, getuikit

it seems uikit3 framework has problem in Microsoft Edge browser.
Even when you try to visit https://getuikit.com/ website, you see white screen.

with these erros in javascript console

SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'UIkit' is not defined

Is there any solution to repair this bug?

Comment: Which version of Edge do you use? The page works well in Edge Version 105.0.1343.42: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykn1q.png. Besides, the [browser support](https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction#browser-support) of UIkit also says it supports latest Edge.

Comment: I am using UIkit 3.15.7.
I know Uikit 2 has no problem in Microsoft Edge browser. But I must use UIkit 3.x

Comment: Here is my screenshot from https://getuikit.com/ in my Microsoft Edge browser. see https://imgur.com/cdKoOL2

Comment: I installed the latest version of Microsoft Edge. it seems many of problems are gone. but navigation section has still problem with latest version of Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: What problem does it have with navigation section? You can describe with detail and provide the steps to reproduce the issue. You can also provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, I think you're using [Edge Legacy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy-3e779e55-4c55-08e6-ecc8-2333768c0fb0) which is not supported now. You need to [download the new chromium Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). In new Edge, Uikit 3 works well.